# Error logging into a HTTP Server

Tags: python, web-scraping, bots, robots.txt

I'm trying to login into a http server to fetch some tables. The code I'm using is this:

```
MechBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
LoginUrl = 'http://www.jlrvehiclefeedback.com'
LoginData = "username=my_username&password=my_password&do=login"
LoginHeader = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36'}

LoginRequest = urllib2.Request(LoginUrl, LoginData, LoginHeader)
LoginResponse = MechBrowser.open(LoginRequest)
```

however I get this error:

```
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

As you could see, I've defined a `UserAgent` but still can't get through the bot policy.

Comment: Have you tired a different user agent? Is the service maybe expecting more headers than user-agent?

Comment: @Leon This is my own opinion as well. Probably more headers than just the useragent is required. but I don't know what?

Comment: Can you not log in via the web page and check what it sends to the server?

Comment: @Leon : sorry for the rookie question but how should I check it?

Comment: If you use Chrome you can use the developer tools to check the network traffic when logging in